# string arguments are not recognized by SWIG

Tags: c++, string, swig

I have a frustrating problem which got me spend a lot of time dealing with it but I did not find any solution.

I want to use C++ class in PHP with SWIG. I generated my shared object and it works fine for some methods but I've got this error whenever I call the methods with string arguments as their input:

> Fatal error: Type error in argument 2 of `PKI_Buf_initHex`. Expected `SWIGTYPE_p_std__string`

`PKI_Buf_initHex` is the name of the wrapper class which SWIG made automatically. In my C++ code I declare `initHex` method as:

```
int initHex(const string x) 
{..}
```

I included `typemaps.i` and `std_string.i` in my interface file but I got the same error message.

I truly would appreciate if anyone can help me with this issue.

Comment: You must have a `using namespace std;` or `using std::string;` in your header. The first is very bad form in general, and very, very bad for SWIG. The latter is something SWIG can't handle, either. Declare your function as `int initHex(const std::string x)` (Aside: Why the `const`? You are passing by value here.)

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your help, I checked my header file and I had using namespace std; so I changed it to "using std::string" and also changed my function to "int initHex(const std::string x), but nothing has changed. I got the same error :(. any idea? (Aside: I did not implement the code by my self, I did not see the source code either, all I have are header file and object file and I must develop the code in PHP for some usages.)

Comment: Actually I checked the SWIG wrap.cpp file for my code and I found out that SWIG recognized the string type well:

Comment: You've probably just got `%include <std_string.i>` too late in your SWIG interface file - it needs to be before SWIG sees any usage of `std::string`.

Comment: @Flexo: Obviously that's my ridiculous fault. Thank you so much for your help and I really appreciate your level of profession in debugging ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to have:

```
%include <std_string.i>
```

Early enough in the SWIG interface (i.e. before `std::string` is first seen).

Comment: Where can I find information about others things like this? Is this needed in order to work with std::map, std::vector, etc ...?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda I just read the swig source and libraries if the documentation doesn't make it clear

Comment: It is documented here http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_nn14 along with info about vectors.