# not able to return QString from c++ function to PERL function by using SWIG

Tags: c++, qt, swig, perl

I have c++ code (Includes Qt also), i want to call those functions by using Perl.
Which we can do by using SWIG, so I have implemented interfaces and did all the stuff need to use them in Perl script.

I have a function in c++ which returns a QString value,

```
QString get_string()
{
  return QString("mystring");
}
```

I have written one more class which will be used in perl script where i have a function which calls this get_string() function and returns const char*.

```
const char* get_const_string()
{
   QString str = get_string();

 **//here I print str and str .toLocal8Bit().constData()
 //both are printing the text which i shoud get here**

   return str.toLocal8Bit().constData();

   //here I have tried diff combinations also, as 
   // return str.toStdString().c_str();
}
```

The problem is, in  get_const_string() function, I could get the string I wanted, but when I call this function in my perl script, I am getting undefine value i.e **null string**

.

Any idea, what is the problem here ??

I am using perl5, Qt4.8.4

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the `str` variable in `get_const_string()` function is local, and destroys as soon as program goes out of scope? As a result, the pointer to char that the function returns points to a invalidated memory?

Comment: What @vahancho said is absolutely true but I would also like to point out that even if `str` would not be local, object returned by `toLocal8bit ()` is also temporary so it can't be used in return statement (`constData ()` just returns its internals)

Comment: @vahancho and Predelnik  : What could you people suggest then, is there a way ??

Comment: I am facing the same issue even with int also (one more function which returns int), I have tried by returning constant (ex: 10) even then i am not receiving any thing.

Answer (score 1):

if you cant use a `QString` return value, maybe you can use `std::string`.

if both fail and you do not have limitations, you could do some dirty trick:

```
QString get_string()
{
  static QByteArray arr;
  QString str = getString();
  arr = str.toLocal8Bit();
  return arr.constData();
}
```

note that the `arr` variable will not be free'd untill your app is running

edit: found a possible solution to just use `std::string` ... [string arguments are not recognized by SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236150/string-arguments-are-not-recognized-by-swig)

Comment: I am facing the same issue even with int also (one more function which returns int), I have tried by returning constant (ex: 10) even then i am not receiving any thing.  so I think problem is something else.